# How can I get the value of an entity from LuisResult object? (LUIS with Bot Framework .NET)

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, bots, azure-language-understanding

Below is the JSON when I call my LUIS api endpoint.

```
  {
        "query": "How do I install citrix?",
        "topScoringIntent": {
            "intent": "Setup Instructions",
            "score": 0.9999997
        },
        "intents": [
            {
                "intent": "Setup Instructions",
                "score": 0.9999997
            },
            {
                "intent": "OS Availability",
                "score": 0.0000021111066
            },
            {
                "intent": "Service Guide",
                "score": 8.18181149e-7
            },
            {
                "intent": "Service Description",
                "score": 5.55555232e-7
            },
            {
                "intent": "None",
                "score": 9e-9
            },
            {
                "intent": "Greeting",
                "score": 1.41666667e-9
            },
            {
                "intent": "Compassion",
                "score": 8.1e-10
            },
            {
                "intent": "Images",
                "score": 8.1e-10
            }
        ],
        "entities": [
            {
                "entity": "citrix",
                "type": "Service",
                "startIndex": 17,
                "endIndex": 22,
                "resolution": {
                    "values": [
                        "Citrix Receiver"
                    ]
                },
                "role": ""
            }
        ],
        "sentimentAnalysis": {
            "label": "positive",
            "score": 0.7695234
        }
    }
```

I am trying to get the string "Citrix Receiver" from below.

Below is my code

```
LuisResult result
var strEntity = result.Entities[0].Resolution.Values[0]
```

but I cannot apply indexing to an expression of type `ICollection<object>`. It looks as though `resolution` is defined as a dictionary and upon researching, I have seen other JSON bodies with the `resolution` having multiple key value pairs. Is it possible the body has changed but the Luis extension in the MS Bot Builder Framework has not?

Thanks.

Comment: To solve same problem: extract data from `"resolution": { "values": ["xxxxxxxxx"]}`, I'm using **var resval = result.Entities[0].Resolution.Values.Select(s => ((List<object>)s)[0]).FirstOrDefault();**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem previously to get a list of resolved entities, I resolved it using the following code:

```
result.Entities.First().Resolution.Values.Select(s => JArray.Parse(s.ToString()).Distinct().ToList();
```

So for you it may be a bit shorter like:

```
result.Entities.First().Resolution.Values.First(s => JArray.Parse(s.ToString());
```